# Importing the Stop Azure V2 VMs runbook

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I am trying to follow the instructions on Microsoft's docs to [create an Azure Automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-cost-management-budget-scenario#create-the-azure-budget). I think the docs are not up to date.

I am stuck at section 7: "Import the Stop Azure V2 VMs runbook". They tell me to select "Edit" but there is no Edit on this page.

Could anyone tell me how to do what they want me to do in the current UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to navigate to the imported runbook and press edit. its there.

[image]
[image]